# ipmitool for windows

Tags: windows, serial-port

ipmitool is used to configure ipmi driver which enables serial communication over LAN port. Is there any ipmitool for Windows? Can we download the ipmi source code and build it for Windows? Please share the instructions on how to build it Windows.

Comment: Check here: http://ipmiutil.sourceforge.net/docs/ipmisw-compare.htm

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Building IPMI for Windows:**

1. Install Cygwin onto your windows system:   Cygwin

   While installing Cygwin, choose gcc and crypto packages in addition to default package.
2. Download the ipmitool source code from [ipmitool](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ipmitool/files/ipmitool/1.8.12/)
3. Unzip, configure and build ipmitool.

   cd ipmitool-1.8.12

   ./configure --enable-intf-lanplus

   make
4. Packaging IPMI binary and related dlls into a zip file.

   mkdir ipmitool

   cp  ipmitool-1.8.12/src/.libs/ipmitool.exe ipmitool/

   cp /bin/cygwin1.dll ipmitool/

   cp /bin/ cygcrypto-1.0.0.dll ipmitool/

   cp /bin/cygz.dll ipmitool/

   cp /bin/cyggcc_s-1.dll ipmitool/

   tar -zcvf ipmitool.tar ipmitool
5. Unzip the file, ipmitool.tar in your destination host. Some of the sample commands:

   ipmitool.exe -I lan -U username -P password -H hosname sensor

   ipmitool.exe -I lanplus -U username -P password -H  hosname -C 3 sol activate

Comment: After building ipmitool.exe, will it run in Powershell, or do you need Cygwin?

Comment: when I execute the `cp /bin/cyggcc_s-1.dll ipmitool/`, there is ` No such file or directory`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MobaXterm for Windows (alternative to Cygwin) and download the ipmitool plugin for it.

http://itsaboutlinux.blogspot.nl/2016/03/ipmitool-for-mobaxterm.html

Answer (score 1):

I'll add a couple things I came across.  As Jason mentioned just above, ipmitool moved to github.  There is a very comprehensive build and install document in the INSTALL file of the source listing.

I googled Cygwin DLL dependencies and found that cygwin produces a tool specifically for this called "cygcheck"

When I ran it against the newly built ipmitool.exe, it produced:

```
C:\users\user1\documents\ipmitool-master\src\ipmitool.exe - os=4.0 img=0.0 sys=5.2
    C:\cygwin64\bin\cygwin1.dll - os=4.0 img=0.0 sys=5.2
"cygwin1.dll" v0.0 ts=2021-03-29 09:42
    C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNEL32.dll - os=10.0 img=10.0 sys=10.0
  "KERNEL32.dll" v0.0 ts=2022-01-18 10:29
    C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll - os=10.0 img=10.0 sys=10.0
    "ntdll.dll" v0.0
    C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNELBASE.dll - os=10.0 img=10.0 sys=10.0
    "KERNELBASE.dll" v0.0
    C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll (already done)
    C:\WINDOWS\system32\api-ms-win-core-fibers-l2-1-1.dll - os=6.3 img=6.3 sys=6.3
    "api-ms-win-core-fibers-l2-1-1.dll" v0.0 ts=2013-08-22 08:04
    C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll (already done)
    C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNEL32.dll (already done)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else is trying to do this more recently...

Cygwin now uses OpenSSL 1.1 and the ipmitool 1.8.12 source code and cygwin version mentioned in Ashok's [above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13610777/3042932) assumed OpenSSL 1.0.

This might be fixed in upcoming release 1.8.19, but as of 1.8.18 it's not, so you'll have to download the latest source from GitHub:  https://github.com/ipmitool/ipmitool 
(they moved from SourceForge)

Also, you'll need from cygwin_setup to also install:

- automake
- autoconf
- libtool

Then you can run

```
cd ipmitool-master/ ; ./bootstrap && ./configure && make
```

(configure includes lanplus plugin by default now)

I haven't tried to copy the cygwin DLLs to another machine as solution mentioned, but if you want to do that, you'd need cygcrypto-1.1.dll instead of 1.0 above.